# Append Text (Single Letter) to the end of each line in a text file

Tags: python, csv, text

Below is an example of the text file I am working with:

```
437868313,2436413,Wyatt,Trenton,08/21/2003,211000010262002,211000010262002,2014,01,54435A000,510,Social Studies (Grade 5),08/14/2013,5-2,02,0,02,02,01,,,,,,100,05/29/2014,
437868313,2436413,Wyatt,Trenton,08/21/2003,211000010262002,211000010262002,2014,01,53235A000,500,Science (Grade 5),08/14/2013,5-2,02,0,02,02,01,,,,,,100,05/29/2014,
437868313,2436413,Wyatt,Trenton,08/21/2003,211000010262002,211000010262002,2014,01,58035A000,560,Physical Education (Grade 5),08/14/2013,5-2,02,0,02,02,01,,,,,,1,05/29/2014,
```

I am trying to add simply the letter 'S' to the end of every other line. So, above, there 3 total records. Right after 05/29/2014, I want to insert the S. So a every record would look like:

```
437868313,2436413,Wyatt,Trenton,08/21/2003,211000010262002,211000010262002,2014,01,54435A000,510,Social Studies (Grade 5),08/14/2013,5-2,02,0,02,02,01,,,,,,100,05/29/2014,S
```

I realize this would be Oh so simple converting to CSV and working with excel, but I'm getting all sorts of formatting issues on the transfer back to txt. Wanted to take a crack at it with python. I'm trying to use append, from what I understand, write will overwrite my existing file:

```py
myFile = open("myFile.txt", "a")
    for line in myFile:
        myFile.write('S')
```

I don't use python often, I'm wondering how I can index it so it starts with line 2, and appends the very end of the line after the comma, like I noted above.

Comment: Take a look at [`file.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: I know the question is about python but I can't resist mentioning that this is a very simple `sed -i 's/$/S/' <yourfile>` on systems with *sed*.

Comment: There is a difference between "every other line" and "every record"

Comment: Sorry, I meant `sed -i '1~2s/$/S/' <yourfile>`.

Comment: There are many answers to this question that append the `S` to *every* line as the title suggests.  However, in the question, the OP states he only wants to append it to *every other line*.  (I was confused by this too.)  Maybe consider updating the title?

Comment: Yes -- I mean every record -- end of every record -- My apologies

Comment: Well, this lets the other half of the answers appear silly.  I'll edit mine.

Comment: My one is wrong also. No need to test for even numbered lines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to read the file line by line and then output line by line again.  This is *much* simpler than using CSV or even spread sheet processing software which truly scares me.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as istr:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as ostr:
        for i, line in enumerate(istr):
            # Get rid of the trailing newline (if any).
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if i % 2 == 0:
                line += 'S'
            print(line, file=ostr)
```

If you are still using Python 2, use

```
ostr.write(line + '\n')
```

instead of the `print`.

**Update:** If you want to append to *every* (as opposed to every other) line, simply use:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as istr:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as ostr:
        for line in istr:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') + 'S'
            print(line, file=ostr)
```

Comment: This was it --- the rstrip was the key ingredient ... thanks for your help too, @b10n

Answer (score 3):

Open a file for reading and for writing, and enumerate the input file. Idenfity the even lines using mod 2. Append the s to to the even lines and write to the output file.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as infile, with open('outfile.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(infile):
        if lineno % 2 == 0:
            line = line + 'S'
        outfile.write(line)
```

OP wants every record as per his edit so there is no need to test for even lines.

```
import os

with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as infile, with open('outfile.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
       line = line.replace(os.linesep, 'S' + os.linesep)
       outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I like this method -- for some reason when I run the script, though, it generates the output file but does not append the 'S' -- basically creates a copy of my original file -- Is this Python 2 or 3 ? (I tried both). The code logic seems correct.

Comment: I forgot to reassign line after appending the 'S' but have since edited my post. Try again. `line = line + 'S'` is the line i updated.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it only adds the 'S' to the very end of the file ... does not add to any lines .. which i'm guessing means it's reading the file as one giant line -- not sure why it would be doing this, they are definitely broken up into lines (records).

Comment: I didn't account for newlines. I have updated my answer, again!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
filename = "file.txt"
file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
    print line.replace("\n","S\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to open the file as one chunk and replace the comma and linebreak with and S a comma and a linebreak.

```
open("data.txt").read().replace(',\n','S,\n').write()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
myFile = open("myFile.txt", "a")
Colist = str(myFile.read()).split('\n')
for line in Colist:
    myFile.write(line + 'S' + '\n')
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to the code sample you provided? I think that would be helpful.