# Python Writing a text at the end of each sentence in the file

Tags: python, file

```
f=open('file.txt', 'a', 
encoding='utf-8')
f.write('+1/n')
f.write('+2/n')


f.close()
```

In file.txt, the result is

```
Line 1
Line 2
+1
+2
```

I want this to be

```
Line 1+1
Line 2+2
```

How can I write a text at the end of each sentence?

Comment: Don't you mean `\n` and not `/n`?  Looks like the code you posted isn't the code you ran.

Comment: You need to read the file, then write the line again the the something new at the end of each

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append Text (Single Letter) to the end of each line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923186/append-text-single-letter-to-the-end-of-each-line-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file and read in the lines with `readlines()`. Then seek back to the beginning and write the lines with you addition. Something like:

```
with open(path,'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for i, line in enumerate(map(str.strip, lines)):
        f.write(f'{line}+{i+1}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
with open('file.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') as fr:
    lines = fr.readlines()

with open('file.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as fw:
    for i,l in enumerate(lines):
        fw.write(f"l+{i+1}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Original text file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Code:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open("file.txt", "w") as out_f:
        for i, j in enumerate(lines):  # i represents the index of the line starting at 0. j represents the line itself
            out_f.write(j.strip("\n") + f"+{i + 1}\n")
```

File after output:

```
line 1+1
line 2+2
line 3+3
line 4+4
```