# append an element to every row of a jagged array

Tags: python, awkward-array

I am trying to add a 0 to every row of a [jagged array](http://awkward-array.org).
I want to go from

`<JaggedArray [[1 2 3] [1 2]]>`

to

`<JaggedArray [[1 2 3 0] [1 2 0]]>`

so that when I grab the -1th index, I get 0. Currently I'm padding every row to the length of the biggest row + 1, then filling nans with 0, which works, but I am wondering if there's a better way.

I saw that there's a class AppendableArray that has a .append() function, but I'm not sure how to convert between the two.
I'm using awkward 0.12.22, and the data is read out of a ROOT file with uproot 3.11.0

Comment: What do you mean by a JaggedArray? They are not a basic datatype in Python, do you mean list of a list or did you create your own class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923186/append-text-single-letter-to-the-end-of-each-line-in-a-text-file Try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is too short to be an answer, but

1. Upgrade to Awkward 1.x (you can still import `awkward0` and use `ak.from_awkward0` and `ak.to_awkward0` to go back and forth in the same process).
2. Create an array of single-item lists, perhaps in NumPy (`ak.from_numpy`), perhaps by slicing a one-dimensional array with `np.newaxis`.
3. Concatenate it with your other array using `ak.concatenate` with `axis=1`. The first dimension needs to be the same (`len` of both arrays must be equal), but the second dimensions are unconstrained.

Comment: For documentation, see awkward-array.org, especially the Python reference.